# DataGrid not executing PropertyChanged when value is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

So i've got this DataGrid and these following classes but i won't get into the PropertyChanged event of the DataNodeModel when i edit some of the values inside the DataGrid.

This is the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid 
    Grid.Row="0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Model.DataNodeModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
    CanUserAddRows="True" 
    CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    CanUserSortColumns="True" 
    CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Model.SelectedDataNodeModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    IsReadOnly="False" 
    IsEnabled="True"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Title" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"  
            Width="70" 
            />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="DefaultValue" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=DefaultValue}"  
            Width="70"  
            />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Type" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" 
            Width="70" 
            />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Id" 
            Binding="{Binding Path=Id, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
            Width="70" 
            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Also this is the class of my DataNodeModel which is the ItemsSource of my DataGrid:

```
public class DataNodeField : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string mDefaultValue, mId, mTitle, mType;

    public string Id
    {
        get { return mId; }
        set
        {
            mId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return mTitle; }
        set
        {
            mTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Type
    {
        get { return mType; }
        set
        {
            mType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string DefaultValue
    {
        get { return mDefaultValue; }
        set
        {
            mDefaultValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Also this is how my Model looks like (most of the stuff removed because it doesn't add to the example:

```
    internal partial class DataNodeViewModel {
             ...

        private ObservableCollection<DataNodeField> mDataNodeModel;

        private DataNodeField mSelectedDataNodeModel;
        public DataNodeField SelectedDataNodeModel
        {
            get { return mSelectedDataNodeModel; }
            set
            {
                mSelectedDataNodeModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDataNodeModel");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<DataNodeField> DataNodeModel
        {
            get { return mDataNodeModel; }
            set
            {
                if (SelectedDataNodeModel != null)
                {
                   //Do Stuff
                }
                mDataNodeModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DataNodeModel");
            }
        }
```

So i really can't figure out why the i the PropertyChanged of my DataNodeModel won't get executed when i change values inside the DataGrid. Already looked for a couple of days and don't know why this happens. Can somebody please help? (=

Comment: Your `ItemsSource` binding looks suspicious. Why is it `TwoWay`? Why do you need the whole bunch of notifications for it? What element is `root`?

Comment: And the answer is: you have not applied the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute to the `propertyName` parameter of the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

Comment: @Kazoooka, what is `root` in your bindings? Is it a control? Does it have a property named `Model`? Are there rows in the grid? Why is your viewmodel a partial class? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @dymanoid It's TwoWay because something doesn't work, and they blindly add everything intellisense has to offer without knowing what any of it means, because nobody thinks of reading the documentation or using the debugger.

Comment: @Kazoooka please add some code regarding your "root" element.

Comment: By default, @Kazooka, no properies of the row item will be updated until focus leaves *the row*. After editing a cell value, are you clicking outside the row?

Comment: Another point I noticed is that if DataNodeViewModel is internal, you can’t declare a public property of that type. The property root.Model can at most be internal, not public, if that’s its declared type. And if it’s not public, you can’t bind to it.

Comment: I would have to post a lot of company internal code for that. But it's definately not because the class is internal.
@dymanoid: Where dio i have to put the [CallerMemberName] attribute?

Comment: @Kazoooka, please read my comment one more time. I've pointed out exactly.

Comment: @Kazoooka CallerMemberName is not the issue in this case (you should certainly use it, though). I tested that. Please answer my questions above. I am trying to help you. Why are you certain that `internal` isn't the issue? Is `Model` declared as `object` or INPC or something?